# MD5 base64 hash is different when compiled in Delphi as 32-bit or 64-bit - how can I make them the same?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am using Delphi XE2 and the below code to create an MD5 base64 hash to use with Amazon MWS. It works if I compile it for 32-bit Windows, but if I compile for 64-bit windows the return hash changes. What is causing this and how can I change this so that they return the same hash?

```
function getMd5HashString(value: string): string;
var
  MessageDigest: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
  Content: TBytes;
begin
  Content := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
  MessageDigest:=TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  Result:=Data.Cloud.CloudAPI.EncodeBytes64(MessageDigest.HashBytes(Content));
end;
```

Thansk in advance.

Edit:

I am using the above function in the following test;

```
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit2.Text := getMd5HashString(Edit1.Text);
end;
```

I am passing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

as the string, just to test with. If I compile the program with a Target Platform of Windows 32-bit the returned hash is;

I3pK/R+hpYOKY1IQRviZbQ==

Whereas if I compile the program with a Target Platform of Windows 64-bit I get;

bmkkAOXGhLdDFCUuNBuSxw==

I hope that answers you David?

Edit2: Full program as suggested by David;

```
unit ContentHashTest;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Data.Cloud.CloudAPI, IdGlobal, IdHash, IdHashMessageDigest,
  IdCoder, IdCoderMIME, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    function getMd5HashString(value: string): string;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit2.Text := getMd5HashString(Edit1.Text);
end;

function TForm1.getMd5HashString(value: string): string;
var
  MessageDigest: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
  Content: TBytes;
begin
  Content := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
  MessageDigest:=TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  Result:=Data.Cloud.CloudAPI.EncodeBytes64(MessageDigest.HashBytes(Content));
end;

end.
```

That was my starting attempt. After David's suggestion below I changed this to;

```
unit ContentHashTest;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, IdGlobal, IdHash, IdHashMessageDigest,
  IdCoder, IdCoderMIME, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    function getMd5HashString(value: string): string;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit2.Text := getMd5HashString(Edit1.Text);
end;

function TForm1.getMd5HashString(value: string): string;
var
  MessageDigest: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
  Content: TIdBytes;
begin
  Content := TIdTextEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
  MessageDigest := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  try
    Result := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeBytes(MessageDigest.HashBytes(Content));
  finally
    MessageDigest.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Unfortunately with the same differing results.

Win32 = I3pK/R+hpYOKY1IQRviZbQ==

Win64 = bmkkAOXGhLdDFCUuNBuSxw==

Comment: Can you make it clear what you are expecting to see, and what you feel is wrong. Is the error in the value produced by `HashBytes`, or the value returned by `EncodeBytes64`? Can we reproduce the behaviour? Have you verified that the input string, `value`, is the same in both versions of the program?

Comment: Hi David, thank you. I have edited the question.

Comment: I think the problem is coming from the `HashBytes` as this returns a different result for each platform. `$nis` for Win64 and `#zJ?????cRF??m` for Win32.

Comment: @ClintCronwright hashing bytes is generally not affected by an app's bitness. Something else is going on.

Comment: Using the latest version of Indy 10 with XE2, I get the same result in both 32bit and 64bit: `I3pK/R+hpYOKY1IQRviZbQ==`. Looking at the revision history, there were some hash-related fixes made in 2014, which is after XE2's release.

Comment: Thank you for the information Remy, I plan to upgrade my Indy today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I turned the extracts in the question into this complete program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  IdGlobal,
  IdCoderMIME,
  IdHashMessageDigest;

function getMd5HashString(value: string): string;
var
  MessageDigest: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
  Content: TIdBytes;
begin
  //Content := TIdTextEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value); // for older versions of Indy
  Content := IndyTextEncoding_UTF8.GetBytes(value);
  MessageDigest := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  try
    Result := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeBytes(MessageDigest.HashBytes(Content));
  finally
    MessageDigest.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  Writeln(getMd5HashString('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'));
  Readln;
end.
```

I'm using Indy to perform all of the conversions: text to UTF-8 bytes, MD5 hashing, and the base64 encoding. But you should use any libraries for this, since they should all give the same output.

This program produces the same output for 32 and 64 bit, as would be expected:

> I3pK/R+hpYOKY1IQRviZbQ==

You report different behaviour though, so what could be the cause? I can think of the following possible explanations:

1. You are not in fact passing the same input value to the function in both versions.
2. `TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes` is defective.
3. `TIdHashMessageDigest5.HashBytes` is defective.
4. `Data.Cloud.CloudAPI.EncodeBytes64` is defective.

In any case, I don't see any sense in using `Data.Cloud.CloudAPI` to perform base64 encoding, although I have no reason to believe that it does not work. Since you are already using the Indy library, it makes more sense to do that uniformly.

I cannot tell from here which of the above explanations is the cause of what you report. You should be able to debug this further to find out. Look at the output of each step in the process to figure out where the behaviour varies.

---

**Update:** I've managed now to reproduce the error, but only by using the version of Indy that ships with XE2. I was using a more up-to-date version of Indy in my initial experiments.

The problem appears to be item 3 in my list. This gives incorrect results under the x64 compiler.

You should solve the problem by finding a different MD5 implementation. My recommendation is to do this by upgrading Indy.

Comment: Hi David, thank you. I ran in to a problem with IndyTextEncoding_UTF8 and resolved that by changing it to TIdTextEncoding.UTF8 as per this [link](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=247040&tstart=-1). However I still get the same 2 different results depending on the platform I compile for.

Comment: So keep debugging and narrow it down. Remember that there are many different Indy versions. I guess I am not using the same Indy as you. Perhaps your Indy has a defect. Also notice that I provided a complete program that can be pasted directly into the IDE and compiled as is. That makes life much easier.

Comment: OK, I've reproduced the issue, but only by using the Indy that ships with XE2. See the update

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much. I will look for a different MD5 implementation.

Comment: Clint, best is probably to update your Indy version.

Comment: Just to confirm, I tried this on XE3 and it works perfectly. So it is absolutely something to do with Indy and XE2. Thanks again David.

Comment: Upgrading Indy is a good idea anyway. The XE2 64 bit compiler is a bit flaky also so if you can move to a later version of Delphi that would be wise. Using Indy for all these conversions is a really good idea, save mixing libraries.